# rendering problems with replacing html with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a page on my website I'm loading HTML through AJAX calls and replace the content of a div with the new received HTML. While replacing a fadeOut and fadeIn effect take place, so the result is that the div fades out, and fades in with new HTML.

This all works fine, but sometimes the new HTML gets rendered weirdly after the fadeIn effect. It's a small difference, but on large pages it's very clear to see:

---

### [image: Example of good and bad HTML rendering]

This rendering problem only occur with big HTML replacements (e.g 5+ divs with tables inside them).

My JQuery script:

```
function renderPage(html)
{
    var speed = 200;
    var container = $("#page-container");

    container.fadeOut(speed, function() {
        container.html(html).fadeIn(speed);

        // add form submit listener
        $("form").submit(onFormSubmit);
    });
}
```

I've also tried "chaining" the method calls, but is has the same rendering problem:

```
container.fadeOut(speed).html(html).fadeIn(speed, function() { ... });
```

So my question is how can fix this or ensure the HTML being rendered properly?

Comment: Is it identical with all browsers? it seems to be a browser problem, not your code

Comment: I've seen it with Firefox and Chrome (and not tested it in any other browser yet). So I don't think it's a browser problem, but I also can't find any error/problem with my code. I bytheway forgot to mention that the rendering problem only occurs with big HTML replacements

Comment: Don't use jquery to fadeIn. Use a [css transition](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/), the behavior is usually more consistent across browser

Comment: With css transitions I don't have the problem anymore, so it works :) thanks!